# VBA Excel problem with convertion PDF file to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I would like to convert my PDF file to Excel.

I saw a good solution in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jeJR_v6TZOQ

but unfortunately with my code:

```
 Option Explicit
 Option Compare Text

 Sub pdftoExcel()
 Dim pdfPath As String
 Dim excelPath As String
 Dim fileName As String
 Dim xlWorkbook As Workbook
 Dim xlWorksheet As Worksheet
 Dim wordApp As New Word.Application
 Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
 Dim wordRange As Word.Range

 pdfPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\pdf\"
 excelPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\xl\"

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.StatusBar = False

 wordApp.Visible = True

 fileName = VBA.Dir(pdfPath)

 While fileName <> ""
   If fileName Like "*.pdf" Then
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(pdfPath & fileName, Format:="PDF Files", ReadOnly:=True)
    Set wordRange = wordDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range
    wordRange.WholeStory
    
    Set xlWorkbook = Excel.Workbooks.Add
    Set xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    
    wordRange.Copy
    
    xlWorksheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    xlWorkbook.SaveAs (excelPath & VBA.Replace(fileName, ".pdf", ".xlsx"))
    
    xlWorkbook.Close False
    wordDoc.Close False
   End If

   fileName = VBA.Dir(1)
  Wend

 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Application.StatusBar = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 MsgBox "Done", vbInformation

 Call Shell("explorer.exe " & excelPath, vbNormalFocus)
    
    
 End Sub
```

at the line of:

```
     xlWorksheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

I have an error:

**Method of paste special worksheet failed**

when I change to

```
   xlWorksheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

Excel says, that it can't paste the data.

How could I easily convert my PDF document to the Excel one?

Comment: What content into these PDF files: text, tables, pictures or mix of it?

Comment: Mix of it to be honest. I used another one which instead of text threw the rectangle with a textbox inside. Is there any solution to covert PDF to pure Excel text or even CSV? This is what I am after.